Groovy multiline string not adding \r\n
I just updated Groovy to the latest 4.0.24 version. But when I run my tests, I get an unexpected test failure with the simple test:
        assert string == """Aaa := Bbb
Ccc := Ddd"""

Assertion failed: 

assert string == """Aaa := Bbb Ccc := Ddd"""
       |      |
       |      false
       'Aaa := Bbb\r\nCcc := Ddd'

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createAssertError(InvokerHelper.java:414)
    at com.anrisoftware.globalpom.core.strings.MapToTableStringTest.with defaults to string(MapToTableStringTest.groovy:25)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)

The syntax for """ means in Groovy a multi-line string. That means, the newline between Bbb and Ccc should be preserved. How come there is no newline? I did not find anything in the official documentation that the behavior changed in Groovy. I also tried with ''', same error.
Edit:
If I do like this below, at least the new line is preserved now.
        assert string == new String("""Aaa := Bbb
Ccc := Ddd""")

Assertion failed: 

assert string == new String("""Aaa := Bbb Ccc := Ddd""")
       |      |  |
       |      |  'Aaa := Bbb\nCcc := Ddd'
       |      false
       'Aaa := Bbb\r\nCcc := Ddd'

But the newline is just with a \n and not \r\n. It should be \r\n because I'm in Windows.

I did a workaround with assert string == "Aaa := Bbb${L}Ccc := Ddd" where L is the 'line.separator' property.

Have you checked, what's literally in the file for line-breaks (e.g.
with a hex-editor or try switching between unix/win LB and see if your
version control notices a difference).  Being on windows implies
a default, but the file can have line-breaks other than the default.  If
your test is so sensitive, I'd rather write \r\n in my expected string
than to rely on the way the file is written.

What version of groovy are you using before upgrade?

i see the same behavior on windows for groovy 2.4 & 4.0.3 println '''<new-line-here>'''.size() - prints 1 no matter if file has CRLF line breaks or just LF.

seems the multiline string in groovy always delimited with LF...

assertion has a problem printing LF for multiline string

The previous Groovy version that I used was 4.0.13. I tried to save the Groovy file both with Unix and Windows line ending, it doesn't matter. The only difference is that, before I developed in Linux. Now I tried the same in Windows, and I get the assertion error. @daggett seems right
